# Set Cassandra logging location

Tags: cassandra

I am using Cassandra 3.5 and I want Cassandra to put log-files into the `/var/log/cassandra` folder. I noticed that Cassandra uses `logback` as the logging backend and in the file `conf/logback.xml` the appenders are configured per default to create log files at the `${cassandra.logdir}` directory. Where is this property set, and how can I best modify it to `/var/log/cassandra`. Is this even the right place for configuring the logging path or are there more "high-level" options to set?

Answer (score 0):

Add this to **cassandra-env.sh** , and restart the service.:

JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Dcassandra.logdir=/yourdir/your_dir"

By the way, **/var/log/cassandra**, should be default (system.log)

Comment: Unfortunately not working at this time as the Cassandra folks don't think it high enough priority to address, https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-11659